# Web Scrape python, submit search form on website not changing url

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I want to extract the theatres location by searching zipcodes, and extract results.
The website inspect is like this:

```
    <form id="set-location-form" class="ip-geoloc-address" action="/theatres" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><button class="btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-find" name="op" value=" " type="submit"> </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-C5B0Dm8QYZgOzeTv2uf9FlNjWVK-EbcLpDKjRz_HQt4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="ip_geoloc_set_location_form" />
    <div class="form-type-textfield form-item-street-address form-item form-group">
     <input placeholder="Enter your location" class="form-control form-text" type="text" id="edit-street-address" name="street_address" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-submit-address" name="op" value="Go" type="submit">Go</button>
    <button class="change-view btn-map-expand btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-map-expand" name="op" value="Map" type="button">Map</button>
    <button class="change-view btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-change-view" name="op" value="" type="button"></button>
```

> The results on inspect looks like this:

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

> But when I look at page source, it's not there:

```
<div class="region region-content">
<section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">
<div class="view view-theatres view-id-theatres view-display-id-page view-dom-id-8a00da3218aaa60e6d4d49fd07033c0b wrapper-container-box">
<div class="attachment attachment-before fix-wrapper">
<div class="view view-theatres view-id-theatres view-display-id-attachment_1">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="ip-geoloc-map view-based-map">
```

I tried these two codes but not working.
import requests

```
url = 'https://www.imax.com/theatres/'
data = {'street_address':'78759'}
r = requests.get(url, params=data)
with open("requests_results.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)


data = { 'street_address':'94704'}
# Get the page
# use .post
# send the data
url = "https://www.imax.com/theatres/"
response = requests.post(url,data=data)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Any one help, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page uses the lat and lon to make a request for the data. You can mimic the xhr (first getting the lat and lon for the location passed - I use a [free API](https://opencagedata.com/) for this. How you do it is up to you.)

---

You can see the request made here:

[image]

---

The response json has rows containing html against the keys. Example here of output

[image]

---

As the inner values associated with keys in rows is html, I pass it back to BeautifulSoup to handle. Example of html content:

[image]

---

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
apiKey = "yourFreeAPIkey"
address = "78759" 

url = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=" + address + "&key=" + apiKey + "&pretty=1"
res = requests.get(url).json()
data = res['results'][1]['geometry']
lat = data['lat']
lng = data['lng']
date = '2019-03-09'
res = requests.get('https://www.imax.com/showtimes/ajax/theatres?date=' + date + '&lat=' + str(lat) + '&lon=' + str(lng))
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
newData = json.loads(soup.select_one('p').text)
columns = ['movieTitle', 'movieLink', 'theatreLink', 'address','movieFormat', 'times']
baseURL = 'https://www.imax.com'
results = []

for row in newData['rows']:
    soup = bs(row['row'], 'lxml')
    link = baseURL + soup.select_one('a')['href']
    address = soup.select_one('.theatre-address').text.strip()
    movieTitle = soup.select_one('.movie-title').text.strip()
    movieLink = baseURL + soup.select_one('.movie-title a')['href']
    movieFormat = soup.select_one('.movie-format').text.strip()
    times = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.line-items a')]
    results.append([movieTitle, movieLink, link, address, movieFormat, times])
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = columns)
print(df)
```

---

Example results:

[image]